# sed regex replace with quotes

Tags: regex, sed

Suppose I have a text file with many lines, one of them being this:

```
  <property name="HTTP_PORT" value="8080"></property>
```

And I want to change it to this with sed:

```
  <property name="HTTP_PORT" value="80"></property>
```

How would I go about that? I have tried a number of things including these:

```
sed 's/^\(.+\)value=\"8080\"\(.+\)$/\1value=\"80\"\2/g' config.xml
sed 's/^\(.+\)value="8080"\(.+\)$/\1value="80"\2/g' config.xml
sed 's/^\(.+\)8080(.+\)$/\180\2/g' config.xml
sed 's/^\(.+\)\"8080\"\(.+\)$/\1\"80\"\2/g' config.xml
sed 's/^\(.+\)"8080"\(.+\)$/\1"80"\2/g' config.xml
```

but all to no avail. The input and output are always the same.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I will try them and accept the most appropriate one as soon as I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per corrections by @Kevin (Thanks!)

```
echo $'<property name="HTTP_PORT" value="8080"></property>'\
| sed 's/^\(.\+\)value=\"8080\"\(.\+\)$/\1value=\"80\"\2/g'
```

The correct fix is to escape the '.+' the plus sign to achieve '1 or more'.

**Edited original answer (which shows an alternate solution to the problem)** **so given the context you are using, what is wrong with the traditional `.*` (zero or more)**

```
echo $'<property name="HTTP_PORT" value="8080"></property>'\
| sed 's/^\(.*\)value=\"8080\"\(.*\)$/\1value=\"80\"\2/g'
```

** output **

```
<property name="HTTP_PORT" value="80"></property>
```

Also, +1 for anchoring your search targets with '^' and '$'. I have seen cases (similar to what you are doing), where NOT having the anchors greatly increases run time.

I hope this helps.

Comment: For the record, sed needs `\+` for "one or more".

Comment: I appreciate the joint effort. Basically, just the first code snippet in this answer is the answer, which is my first attempt but incorporating @Kevin's comment about sed needing `\+` for "one or more". Thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

How about the direct translation of what you want:

```
sed 's|<property name="HTTP_PORT" value="8080"></property>|<property name="HTTP_PORT" value="80"></property>|g'
```

It's not as "clever" a solution as you or I could find, but it's as straightforward as they come and as you're looking for a static string, it's all you need.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this answer. The XML could be correct yet contain extra whitespace. It's not a matter of being a less clever solution due to the lack of regex. It's just not that robust. (Admittedly, the regex solution isn't foolproof either, but more robust than this.) But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$> cat text
<property name="HTTP_PORT" value="8080"></property>

$> sed --regexp-extended 's/(value=\")[0-9]*/\180/' text
<property name="HTTP_PORT" value="80"></property>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i '\|<property name="HTTP_PORT" value="8080"></property>|s/80//' config.xml
```

or perhaps:

```
sed -i 's/"8080"/"80"/' config.xml
```